# jQuery.post complete function doesn't contain data

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery.post() to send data to web service, recive answer and show it to user.

I have this code:

```
    if (Verify(message)) {
        $.post('@ViewBag.GASU_EP_Address', message)
              .complete(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                  alert('Данные отправлены');
              });
    }
```

jQuery succesfully sends data to server, server process data and return answer. But in my callback function I recive next: status = 'error', jqXHR = undefined, data - unknown object.

I use fiddler to exemine http from web service. Here is sniffed request: http://pastebin.com/ubJHh7qU

Reading this message in fiddler, I see, what service correctly processed my request, and give positive answer for me.

Here is debuged data parametr of callback function
[image]

So, my question is how can I read web service response? As I can see in Fiddler it's just a simple XML.

Comment: Not surprising, the function signature for `complete` is `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

There is updated jQuery ajax functionality here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ depending on what version of jQuery you're using.
You could try.

```
    $.post( "'@ViewBag.GASU_EP_Address", message)
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work. Maybe the problem is in response headers? I didn't see content-length header in web service response.